Segmentation fault while implementing a binary tree in c
I am new to c, but for a project I am implementing a binary tree. here is my code for the functions:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct BSTnode{
  int key;
  int subtree_size;
  struct BSTnode* left;
  struct BSTnode* right;
} TreeNode;

TreeNode* newNode(int value){
  TreeNode *node = malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
  node->key = value;
  node->left = NULL;
  node->right = NULL;
  node->subtree_size = 1;
  return node;
}

TreeNode* insert(TreeNode* root, TreeNode* to_insert){
  if(root == NULL){
    root = newNode(to_insert->key);
  }
  else if(to_insert->key> root->key){
    if(root->right == NULL){
      root->right = to_insert;
      return root;
    }
    else{
      root->right = insert(root->right, to_insert);
    }
  }
  else if(to_insert->key< root->key){
    if(root->left == NULL){
      root->left = to_insert;
      return root;
    }
    root->left = insert(root->left, to_insert);

  }

  root->subtree_size = 1 + (root->left? root->left->subtree_size: 0) + (root->right? root->right->subtree_size: 0);
  return root;
}

int find(TreeNode* root, int value){
  if(root == NULL || root->key == value){
    return root->key;
  }
  else if(value > root->key){
    return find(root->right, value);
  }
  else{
    return find(root->left, value);
  }
}

In my main function, I am reading from a file that contaqins a number on each line that I have to insert into the BST. Each line starts with a letter followed by the number seperated by the space.
int main (int argc, char* argv[]){
  FILE* input;

  input = fopen(argv[1], "r");

  char oper;
  int num;

  TreeNode* root = NULL;
  
  while(fscanf(input, "%c", &oper) != EOF){
    if(oper == 'i'){
      fscanf(input, " %d\n", &num);
      TreeNode* to_insert = newNode(num);
      insert(root, to_insert);
      //printf("operation: %c, num: %d\n", oper, num);
    }
    if(oper == 'r'){
//do some other thing
    }
  }
  if(root == NULL){
    printf("yes\n");
  }
  printf("size: %d\n", root->subtree_size);
  printf("left size: %d\n", root->left->subtree_size);
  printf("right size: %d\n", root->right->subtree_size);
  fclose(input);
}

Running the code prints "yes" then it gives me a seg fault. I have seen another post about a similar problem and the solution was to change the insert function to take in a double pointer for root. Does that work here? Id so, what would it look like? I am not really good with double pointers.
Edit 1: assume fscanf() and the input file are properly used and opened.
Edit2: the input file would look like this:
i 10
i 20
i 30
i 40
i 50
i 60
i 70
i 80
i 90
i 99
i 15
i 14
i 12
i 25
i 28
i 95
i 35
i 38
i 11
i 23
i 22


First off, since you don't check the return value of your fscanf() calls, you have no idea if you have read what you think you read. Actually, you don't even know if you opened input successfully. And if root is NULL, the following printf()'s are following the NULL pointer, which is undefined behavior. Either use a debugger to find out what is happening (recommended), or add more status messages to the read / tree building operations so you see what is happening, not just the end result.

@DevSolar fscanf() and the input file are opened correctly. I shoudl have mentioned that in the post

@DevSolar I have added an example of what the input file would look like

"Running the code prints "yes" then it gives me a seg fault." if(root == NULL){     printf("yes\n");   }   printf("size: %d\n", root->subtree_size); If root is NULL, you must not de-reference it. A segfault is a reasonable potential consequence of doing so.

Your problem:
Your insert() function returns root. But you never assign the return value to anything, at least not in your main():
TreeNode* root = NULL;

while(fscanf(input, "%c", &oper) != EOF){
  // ...
  insert(root, to_insert);

Your root always stays NULL.
How I found out:
gcc -Wall -Wextra -g testme.c -o testme
gdb -tui --args ./testme input.txt
break main
run

And then "n" for next (step over) and "s" for step (step in). Either learn to use gdb from there, or familiarize yourself with a different debugger of your choosing. Doing software development without a debugger is hard. Don't try it.
My fix:
I abhor double pointers. Luckily, there's a simple fix to your problem. In insert(), for the first node received, don't newNode(), just take the node you're given:
if(root == NULL){
  root = to_insert;
}

And in main(), assign the return value to root:
  TreeNode* to_insert = newNode(num);
  root = insert(root, to_insert);

Yet to do:
Note that your program leaks all the memory it allocated.
You need to check root for NULL before accessing root->left and root->right (in case you didn't read any data), and you need to check either of those for NULL again before accessing their respective ...->subtree_size (in case you, as with your example data, have no data at all in one subtree).

doing root = insert(root, to_insert); allows me to print 'size: 17' and then followed by a seg fault. Do you know what is wrong with root->left->subtree_size?

@The-coder-E Your initial value is 10. All following values are larger than 10, and thus go to the right of root. root->left remains NULL, and so root->left->subtree_size is an illegal access. (Did you try using the debugger?)

Thanks so much for the help. I will work out the memory issues later on, as of right now I have more important thinks to do.
